# C++ OpenGL Have a Quad follow the mouse pointer (without Glut)

Tags: c++, opengl, mouse

I'm trying to have a quad follow the mouse pointer. So basically I need to convert screen coordinates to world coordinates. I've seen many posts on this, and tutorials from NeHe and other places, but none of them work properly for me. Almost every time, I get some kind of scaling problem, where the further away I move my mouse from the center of the window, the more offset the quad gets from my mouse.

The code I'm currently trying is from
http://www.3dbuzz.com/forum/threads/191296-OpenGL-gluUnProject-ScreenCoords-to-WorldCoords-problem
but it still has that scaling problem, even though the person in that link says the code worked for him.

How can I get the quad to follow the mouse?

Heres the code (from the render frame function):

```
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
glLoadIdentity();
glTranslatef(0.0f,0.0f,-5.0f);

POINT mouse;
GetCursorPos(&mouse);
ScreenToClient(WindowHandle, &mouse);

GLdouble
    posX1,
    posY1,
    posZ1,
    posX2,
    posY2,
    posZ2,
    modelview[16],
    projection[16];
GLint
    viewport[4];

glGetDoublev(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, modelview);
glGetDoublev(GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX, projection);
glGetIntegerv(GL_VIEWPORT, viewport);

gluUnProject( mouse.x, viewport[1] + viewport[3] - mouse.y, 0, modelview, projection, viewport, &posX1, &posY1, &posZ1);
gluUnProject( mouse.x, viewport[1] + viewport[3] - mouse.y, 1, modelview, projection, viewport, &posX2, &posY2, &posZ2);

GLfloat t = (posZ1 - 0) / (posZ1 - posZ2);

GLfloat
    fX = posX1 + (posX2 - posX1) * t,
    fY = posY1 + (posY2 - posY1) * t;

OutputDebugFloat(fX);
OutputDebugString(", ");
OutputDebugFloat(fY);
OutputDebugString("\n");

glTranslatef(fX, fY, 0);
DrawTile(test.Tex()); // Draws the quad with the specified texture

SwapBuffers(hDC);
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, I appeared to have figured it out. The problem was that I had no background quad. (I removed it so I could have a blank screen while testing this. Bad idea.) Most of the tutorials I tried actually did work, it just was broken because of that.

Edit: I found that 'glReadPixels' drops FPS by quite a bit. I fixed this by only updating the quad position every FPS/60 frames.